# Python extension in C - passing lists back and forth

Tags: c, python-3.x, parameters, wrapper

I have a C library for a device that includes functions like:

```
int GetDevInfo(int *devices);
```

In this case, devices is an array of integers that might have been defined like this:

```
int devices[10]
```

The function will loop through a hardware bus to look for active devices. As it finds them, it puts the device number into the next available spot in `devices[]`, so for example before scanning:

`devices = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}` and a global variable `DeviceCount` knows there are 0 active ones. The function does its magic and decides that devices 5 and 8 are active. So then:

`devices = {5, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}` and `DeviceCount` knows there are 2.

I want the Python function to be something like this.

```
devices = list(range(64))
for i in range(0,len(devices)):  # Set them all to 0
    devices[i] = 0
DeviceCount = 0

# Now we'll update it
DeviceCount = myModule.GetDevInfo(DeviceCount, devices)
```

When it returns, `DeviceCount` might be set to 2, and devices looks like:

```
[5, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I've written code for other wrappers that pass in integers and pass back strings, but I'm not finding any web wisdom to help me with this. I know if I do something like this:

```
def f(a, data):
    a.append(data)

l = [1, 2, 3]
f(l, 4)
```

I get `l=[1, 2, 3, 4]`, but it's not obvious how to get that effect with a Python wrapper to C.

Comment: Suggestion: have the function return just a list, where `len(that_list) == DeviceCount`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, reading the web and lots of trial and error later...

```
static PyObject* LMS_module_timesTwo(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
  int i, numLines;
  PyObject *listObj, *numObj;
  unsigned int n;

  n = PyTuple_Size(args);
  if (1 == n) {
    /* argument 1 should be an list of integers */
    listObj = PyTuple_GetItem(args, 0);
    /* get the number of elements in the list */
    numLines = PyList_Size(listObj);

    /* should raise an error here. */
    if (numLines < 0)   return NULL; /* Not a list */

    for (i=0; i<numLines; i++) {
      numObj = PyList_GetItem(listObj, i);
      n = PyLong_AsUnsignedLong(PyNumber_Long(numObj));
      // This is the action - multiply by 2 for the test case
      n = n * 2;
      PyList_SetItem(listObj, i, Py_BuildValue("i", n));
    }
  } else {
      PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Function expects one argument");
      return NULL;
  }
  return PyLong_FromLong(1);
}
```

With that code as part of the extension (I left out the other structural bits but can post the whole thing if anyone needs them) and this as a Python 3 test program it works swell!

```
   import my_module

   testlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   print("List before multiplying = ",testlist)
   my_module.timesTwo(testlist)
   print("List after multiplying = ",testlist)
```

Thank you to anyone who read this and thought about an answer. My actual code has error checking and stuff in it too, and I'm not concerned about what happens if a program passes in junk since this is a very specific function.

The question originally posed it as passing a list as an array to a C function, so this is closer to the final:

```
static PyObject* LMS_module_timesTwo(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
  int i, numLines;
  PyObject *listObj, *numObj;
  unsigned int n;
  unsigned int carray[64];  // this has to be big enough!

  n = PyTuple_Size(args);
  if (1 == n) {
    /* argument 1 should be an list of integers */
    listObj = PyTuple_GetItem(args, 0);
    /* get the number of elements in the list */
    numLines = PyList_Size(listObj);

    /* should raise an error here. */
    if (numLines < 0)   return NULL; /* Not a list */

    for (i=0; i<numLines; i++) {
      numObj = PyList_GetItem(listObj, i);
      carray[i] = PyLong_AsUnsignedLong(PyNumber_Long(numObj));
    }
    /* Do the actual work on the array */
    someCfunction(carry);  // this modifies the array somehow
    for (i=0; i<numLines; i++) {
      PyList_SetItem(listObj, i, Py_BuildValue("i", carray[i]));
    }
  } else {
      PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Function expects one argument");
      return NULL;
  }
  return PyLong_FromLong(1);
}
```